# Java AEM Query Builder ||

Tags: java, jsp, adobe, aem

I am building a simple meta-data table that gets the data from a query.  I want to be able to query on two options for the 'type' variable.  the || is not working however; when I use this the page crashes.

```
Map<String, String> predicates = new HashMap<String, String>();
            predicates.put("path", searchPath);
            predicates.put("type", "cq:Page||dam:Asset");
            predicates.put("orderby", orderBy);

    QueryBuilder qb = resourceResolver.adaptTo(QueryBuilder.class);
    Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

    Query query = qb.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(predicates), session);
    query.setHitsPerPage(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use groups to query with OR condition. The code for your search should be

```
predicates.put("path", searchPath);
predicates.put("group.p.or", "true");
predicates.put("group.1_type", "cq:Page");
predicates.put("group.2_type", "dam:Asset");
predicates.put("orderby", orderBy);
```

You can use the query builder debugger to play around with the query builder, [http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?*charset*=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%0D%0Agroup.p.or%3Dtrue%0D%0Agroup.1_type%3Dcq%3APage%0D%0Agroup.2_type%3Ddam%3AAsset%0D%0A%0D%0A](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%0D%0Agroup.p.or%3Dtrue%0D%0Agroup.1_type%3Dcq%3APage%0D%0Agroup.2_type%3Ddam%3AAsset%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to have 2 fields that had this notation.  As in you wanted to do type=page||asset but also wanted tagid=(marketing:interest/product && marketing:interest/seller)
tagid.property=jcr:content/cq:tags